# What would be output of SQL query if we include two table without any condition

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Recently i was asked in an interview that, what would be output if we fire a sql query as below:

```
select * from table1 & table2;
```

Will this give a output or it's an error, i got mixed answers when i googled/asked someone. 
Please clarify with details.

Comment: That particular statement is not a valid syntax and will give you an error.  However it's _you_ that need to "clarify with details" what you are looking for.

Comment: This statement is not even valid syntax. But assuming you meant join table 1 and table 2 with valid syntax, you can start here to understand joins: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: Oh, and while you are at it, why not simply input this into a mysql prompt and see what happens?

Comment: @narendrak, check out joins, illustrated in a very clear way, all details in the [Link](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you fix your syntax to

```
select * from table1, table2;
```

you will get a join where every condition is true, which is the same as the *Cartesian product* of the two tables.

```
table1      table2
------      ------
A           1
B           2
C
```

Result:

```
A 1
A 2
B 1
B 2
C 1
C 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do it right, like this:

```
select * from table1, table2;
```

you'll get the cartesian product. Which means, all columns of both tables and each row from one table joined with each row of the other table.